# Why did the Java Spring Boot Build Failed on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to build Java Spring Boot Project on Ubuntu Server. First I clone the project from Github then I try to build it using *`mvn clean install`* or *`mvn clean package`* but none of this is working, It always fails. Even I use `-U`, it gives the same result. Can someone help me with this issue?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX00D.png)

Comment: What error you getting? Can you share error message.

Comment: It would be nice to have full build log, actually. Or you can try analyzing it yourself with adding `-X` argument for debug mode. See https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-verbose-option

Comment: I attached the screenshots sir

Comment: -U is for update snapshots. If you want to skip tests use `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

Comment: Don't post links to images of the error, update the question with the text from the output with the error. It will make it easier for us to read and will allow for those errors to be found when someone has the same problem and is searching with keywords from their errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot (first line), you need to set the `hibernate.dialect` property to a correct value in your application.properties file (or some other propertysource).

Answer (score 0):

As Marco mentioned, check your application.properties or application.yml file. `hibernate.dialect` has to be corrected. 
And if you find that `hibernate.dialect` has no issues then there will issue with `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings` if you code like https://www.journaldev.com/2897/hibernateexception-access-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-null-hibernate-dialect-not-set.